Git alias to rebase onto commit before message
Here's a common workflow:

Make some changes and commit, e.g. git commit -m 'add action buttons'
Make a bunch of interim commits
Realize I want to fix that first commit
Search for the commit SHA in the log and copy it
Rebase onto the commit before the SHA, e.g. git rebase -i asdf123^
Edit the todo list so it pauses on the commit I want to fix
Make the change, amend the commit, and continue rebasing

I'd like an alias to automate steps 4-5, e.g. git fixup add action buttons. The rebase command is:
$ git rebase -i 'HEAD^{/Add action buttons}^'

I think this alias should work, but it doesn't:
[alias]
    fixup = !sh -c 'git rebase --interactive HEAD^{/$@}^'

Curiously, it works if I do git fixup add action, but git fixup add action buttons throws an error: fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD^{/action'.
I think the problem might have to do with quoting, but I can't figure out how to escape the quotes in the alias. I tried this:
[alias]
    fixup = !sh -c 'git rebase --interactive \'HEAD^{/$@}^\''

But this throws another error: fatal: bad config line 2 in file /home/dave/.gitconfig.

Yeah the problem is definitely with word splitting.  HEAD^{/<search>} has to be one word. Doesn’t double quotes work?

Indeed, double-quotes are required, along with $* instead of $@. Namely, "HEAD^{/$*}^"

@ErikMD with that I still get an error: fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD^{/action'

Not sure if it matters but I realized I'm using zsh instead of bash.

May I recommend to look for inspirations at https://words.filippo.io/git-fixup-amending-an-older-commit/ and https://mystor.github.io/git-revise.html ?

As @phd noted you don't need anything new for this, see the git commit --fixup docs and git rebase --autosquash which they point you at. There's other commands with options catering to this workflow too.  edit: and btw Git has message-search syntax, if there's a string most recently used in that commit's message you can say @^{/that string}, there's docs for that in git help revisions.

I would consider setting up fzf(1) or some other fuzzy search for this purpose

What is git fum? Should it be git fixup?

@Guildenstern To search for what? Can fzf search for a commit ID in git log?

@phd short for "fixup message". Thanks and corrected.

@jthill the point is to avoid looking for SHAs and having to remember and type cryptic search strings.

This quote from the git-config(1) man page is useful here:

Shell command aliases always receive any extra arguments provided to the Git command-line as positional arguments.

Care should be taken if your shell alias is a "one-liner" script with multiple commands (e.g. in a pipeline), references multiple
arguments, or is otherwise not able to handle positional arguments added at the end. For example: alias.cmd = "!echo $1 | grep $2"
called as git cmd 1 2 will be executed as echo $1 | grep $2 1 2, which is not what you want.
A convenient way to deal with this is to write your script operations in an inline function that is then called with any arguments
from the command-line. For example `alias.cmd = "!c() { echo $1 | grep $2 ; }; c" will correctly execute the prior example.


With that in mind, we can write your alias like this:
[alias]
  fixup = "!f() { git rebase -i \"HEAD^{/$*}^\" ; }; f"

If I have a commit history like this:
$ git log --oneline -8
423e981 (HEAD -> main) Reformat with gofmt
b9de0cb (origin/main) Refactor Makefile
be4ac65 Integrate options and common_options
042d122 Rename precommit workflow
d0f41ef Fully qualify package name
829bda3 Remove --exact-match from git describe command line
c8de23e Simplify pre-commit execution of golangci-lint
40b071a Update krew index manifest

Then I can write:
git fixup precommit workflow

And end up with a pick list like this:
pick 042d122 Rename precommit workflow
pick be4ac65 Integrate options and common_options
pick b9de0cb Refactor Makefile
pick 423e981 Reformat with gofmt

Which is what you want.

By trying to call out to the shell, like this...
!sh -c '...'

You are calling a shell from a shell, so you have, effectively:
sh -c "sh -c '...'"

And that makes quoting a royal PITA. You end up with something like:
[alias]
  fixup = "!bash -c \"git rebase -i \\\"HEAD^{/\\$*}\\\"\" -- "


Lastly, you should really take a look at stacked git, which sits on top of git and makes a workflow like this ("go back and make changes to an older commit") super trivial. For the above example, I might do something like:
# pop patches after the named patch so that the named patch becomes HEAD
stg goto rename-precommit-workflow
<make changes>

# update the patch
stg refresh

# push all the patches back so that I return the original HEAD of the branch
stg push -a


I might need to start a new thread for this but any idea how to get autocompletion for commits after the fixup command?

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, so opening a new question is probably a good idea (because then you can include examples of the behavior you want).
